# Are save games compatible between Deus Ex Human Revolution and the Director's Cut version?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

If I upgrade to the Director's Cut of Deus Ex Human Revolution on Steam, which is where I also have my prior edition of the same game, will the game download and overlay over the old game and keep my saved game files as is? Or do I have to start all over again?

Comment: To be clear: you are asking how your settings and save games from the base game interact with the Director's Cut version?

Answer (score 3):

The games are treated as separate SKUs, applications, and downloads, and the save files are incompatible. You will have to start over for the Director's Cut.